# ImageButton doesn't scale / adapt according to different resolutions

Tags: android

I have a imagebutton placed inside a RelativeLayout.
However I can't seem to figure out what I need to do in order for the button to scale according to different resolutions.

Here's the content of my activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView1"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:src="@drawable/background" android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:gravity="center"/>

     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:background="@null"
         android:onClick="startVideo"
         android:scaleType="fitCenter"
         android:src="@drawable/button" android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

background.png is an image placed in the mdpi folder (1280x800px), button.png is also placed in the mdpi folder (757x271px).

If I run my app on a 1280x800px resolution (galaxy tab) it looks fine, however when I try to run the app on my phone the ImageButton doesn't scale down - it keeps the original size (757x271px).

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: Your phone must be mdpi, because of this you see same size

Comment: Thanks for the reply talhakosen, it is true that my phone uses the mdpi image - however if I create a smaller image and overwrite the old one, the imagebutton still stays the same size (so the new low res image is scaledup and looks distorted)

Comment: maybe you should use , drawable-small,drawable-normal,drawable-large,drawable-xlarge, instead of dpi folders.

Comment: And after overriding image you should clean your app, because sometimes. R file is not been updated.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to use drawable-small, drawable-normal etc. instead of dpi folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you create alternative layout resources with modifiers like layout-large, layout-small and so on? If you only have one layout it's not guaranteed to scale properly on any screen. Also consider specifying dimensions in **dp** for the related view

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I haven't created layout resources for alternative size. I was hoping it would be possible to only use the same layout and a large image, and downscale that for smaller resolutions. Kinda like the concept of a responsive design in HTML.

Comment: as I've said, try to use fixed dp-dimensions instead of wrap_content for you ImageButton, this may solve your problem

Comment: Maver1ck, I tried using dp dimensions instead of wrap_content - but it still looks the same as wrap_content. In the case of mdpi (160dpi) I believe dp and px are 1:1, oddly this doesn't seem to be the case for me.

Comment: Sounds a bit weird.. dp values should be scaled appropriately. You mentioned your problem was that the view didn't scale down? Try adding maxWidth="" and maxHeight="" to XML attributes of the affected View

Comment: No the ImageView scales just fine (because of the fill_parent params and scaleType), my problem is that the ImageButton doesn't scale down.

Comment: I mean the ImageButton View :) Try setting maxWidth and maxHeigt in dp, so the view won't be able to become larger. Not the best solution but the only one I see in your situation

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on solving this by only using one big image that were scaled down like I wanted to.

So in the end I had to create different versions of the image for the imagebutton, and place them in the correct folders, ie:

```
drawable-large-hdpi
drawable-large-mdpi
drawable-normal-hdpi
drawable-normal-mdpi
etc.
```

I then get the desired result from the ImageButton.
Thanks anyway for the help Maver1ck and talhakosen, your comments helped me understand how the different resource folders work for images and layouts.